# why I cannot cout my declared array character?

Tags: c++

```
char ph[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
```

that is my code and this is how I summon them

```
for(int i=1;i>=3;i++)
         {
             cout<<ph[i]<<" ";
         }
```

but it turn out blank

Comment: Your for loop condition is incorrect. You start off with i=1, and then the condition is i>=3 which isnt true hence the for loop will never run

Comment: but i want to print the a,b,c letters only

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is never going to run.

```
for(int i=1;i>=3;i++)
```

Means start at 1 and while we are greater then 3 continue the loop.  Since we are never greater than 3 the loop ends.

If you want to print the first 3 elements of the array, then you would use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout<<ph[i]<<" ";
```

Comment: i see, thanks , since is 2am i can't think straight sorry